# Using Mercurial, do we need to "hg merge -r 6880" if there is an extra branch?

Tags: mercurial

For Mercurial, right now there is `default` branch and `newfeature` branch... is it true that if I am on
the `newfeature` branch, and do an `hg pull` and `hg update`, it will always ask me to merge? (if there are changesets that I pulled)

Also, it seems that I cannot just do `hg merge`?  I need to use `hg heads` and then look at what the `newfeature` branch's head is (say it is revision `6880`),
then I need to `hg merge -r 6880`?  Because otherwise, will Mercurial merge the `newfeature` branch with the `default` branch automatically?  I cannot do `hg merge -b newfeature`, it seems, as there is no `-b` option for `hg merge`.

Is there an easier way other than using `hg heads` to look for the revision to merge?  Isn't there a more automatic way?

Answer (score 4):

You've got two questions there, let me take them one at a time (with a little paraphrasing):

**Q. When I `hg pull` and get a new head Mercurial suggest I `hg merge`. Do I have to?**

**A.** No.  Mercurial is just warning you you have more heads than than you did, and that if you don't like that arrangement you can merge to stop it.  Named branches are heads, so you'll see that warning if pulling gets you a new head

**Q. If I want to merge one named branch into another do I have to provide the revision number?**

**A**. No.  It's true that `hg merge` will only automatically select heads on the same named branch, but you can do `hg merge -r newfeature` and that merges in the changeset from the point of divergence up to the head on `newfeature` (6880 in your example) **exactly** the same as `hg update -r 6880` would.

In either case, after committing that merge you'll have no heads on `newfeature` (the new, resulting head is on `default` because that was the branch name of your parent before you started the merge.  However, just doing this after the merge:

```
hg update newfeature
...code....
hg commit
```

will create a new head on the `newfeature` branch, and you're right back as you were before the merge, except all of the changes that were on new feature are also available in `default` now.

Comment: For Question #1, you are saying whenever we have branches, then there will be multiple heads, and `hg` will warn you that you have multiple heads, but you don't have to merge, supposing you only work on and care about the `newfeature` branch... is that true?

Comment: This is the first time I tried `hg pull -b newfeature` and then `hg up -r newfeature`, but then when I push, it will say, `abort: push creates new remote heads on branch 'newfeature'!`, and when I `hg merge -r 7002` or `hg merge -r newfeature`, it will say `abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect`  How does this happen?  For some reason, learning `hg` seems harder than learning C++.

Comment: Re:Q1: Yes, multiple branches means multiple heads, yes.  When a pull gets you more heads, Mercurial suggest you use merge to reduce that number if you dn't want more heads.  You can ignore it if you're okay having those new heads (which may be on different branches).

Comment: You'd need to provide more detail for a good answer, but maybe these shots in the dark will help: `hg pull -b newfeature` gets you the remote changesets on that branch.  `hg up -r newfeature` updates your current working directory to the latest changeset in that branch.  Your push could be creating new heads because someone else added changesets on the `newfeature` branch -- pull again and see.  Your merge commands are trying to merge local heads, and you probably need to pull/merge one that's currently remote only.  Read the redbean book.  You need a better conceptual understanding, not tips.

Answer (score 2):

If you pull a changeset or changesets from one branch into another branch that share the same root changeset. Mercurial will have multiple heads as you have so noticed. It will only suggest that you merge when you do an `hg update` on one of the branches.

You shouldn't have to specify which revision to merge to, assuming that you want to merge the `tips` of each of the branches. `hg merge` should suffice.

Your command structure should look as follow

```
hg pull -b 'branchYouWantToPullFrom`
hg update
hg merge
hg commit
```

Answer (score 1):

`hg merge` works in your working copy, which is always connected to a specific branch.

You have to specify a branch name only if you want to merge your current branch with another branch: `hg merge branch_name`.

`hg pull` updates your repository with all remote changes. Then you have to update your working copy, that is connected to a specific branch. So, when you type `hg update` command, you update your working copy with all changes in your current branch. 
If you want to switch to another branch you have to type `hg update branch_name`. You can type `hg branch` to know your current branch.

The only reason to merge with a specific revision is when you have three or more heads, a strange situation probably caused by some `hg push -f` (extremely bad practice). If you are in this situation, the right way to know which revisions you have to merge is `hg heads`. In a normal situation `hg heads` returns one head per branch, so you don't have to merge two heads of different branches if you don't want.

If you're working on a branch and someone has committed and pushed some changes on the same branch, you have to pull and merge before your push, simply with `hg merge`, no revision or branch.

I hope this will help you.